# Display all posts in main category and 1 subcategory

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have defined a custom post type for creating galleries using WP built in gallery functionality.

```
register_post_type( 'my_gallery',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Gallery', 'my-child-theme' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Gallery', 'my-child-theme' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' )
    )
);
```

Also created custom taxonomy for this specific CPT, with a main category 'Galleries', and a subcategory 'History':

```
-Galleries
    -History
```

I also have a template in child theme called *taxonomy-galleries.php* which works as it should, it displays all the posts in galleries, and in history too.

Now what I want is this:
Display all the posts in main category, and display the subcategory history, paged with max 12 elements.

How would I do that?

**Edit** based on @mmm -s answer how to get all the elements in one array:

```
    $all_the_items = array();
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
          $t = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'my-taxonomy' );
                if ($t[0]->parent == 0){
                $properties = array(
                    'title' => get_the_title(),
                    'link' => get_the_permalink() );
                 $all_the_items[] = $properties;
}
endwhile; wp_reset_query();
    $o = get_queried_object();
            $children = get_term_children($o->term_id, $o->taxonomy);
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $this_term = get_term($child);
                $properties = array(
                    'title' => $this_term->name,
    'link' => site_url('/' . $this_term->taxonomy . '/' . $this_term->slug . '/')
                );
    }
```

Comment: you want to display the subcategories on the same page ?

Comment: Yes I want the items from the root category and subcategories (without the items, items in the subcategories will have a separate page for them).

Answer (score 1):

to get the children of the queried object, you can use this code is the file `taxonomy-galleries.php`

```
$o = get_queried_object();
$children = get_term_children($o->term_id, $o->taxonomy);
```

`$children` is an array of term identifiers then you just need to loop over this.